# How to decompose the three rotations rotation matrix to rotation around a single axis in space?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, rigid-transformation

we know that the rotation matrix of a 3 rotations around XYZ in order, will be :

[image: Rotation-Matrix]

and we also know that the trace of the matrix is :

TR = $$\arccos \left ( -1 + \sum_{i=j} R_{ij} \right )$$

if we have the intention of decomposing these 3 rotations into a rotation around a single axis in space, then :

what does

value 1 = $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{(R(3,2) - R(2,3)) }{\sin (TR)}$

value 2 = $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{(R(1,3) - R(3,1)) }{\sin (TR)}$

value 3 = $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{(R(2,1) - R(1,2)) }{\sin (TR)}$

mean ?

and then what will be the

$a1 = value 1 * TR$

$a2=  value 2 * TR$

$a3=  value 3 * TR$

Comment: See the first part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1788804/265466). The individual formulas are simply picking out the elements of the matrix $K = \frac1{2\sin(TR)}(R-R^T)$.

Comment: So which is which? I couldn't find a relation and a physical interpretation by your link

Comment: @amd could you please write your analysis as an answer, I did not find similarities between the values

Comment: @amd thank you for the comment, but I don't get the order of matrice arrays